# facing error while inserting data in database in asp.net mvc web applcaition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am facing error while inserting data in database at below line

```
db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(LiverFunctionTest);
```

Here is my full fucntion  where i am facing error

Function:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are adding class as a parameter to insertonsubmit method pass object instance as a parameter!

```
db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(LiveFuntionTestObject);
```

[Table.InsertOnSubmit Method (TEntity)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi Midhun Mundayadan could you explain your answer